# Python ( Tkinter ) - Text Editor - Find function

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to make some Text Editor in Python with Tkinter but I've encountered a problem .

I've been trying to make a find function for my text editor but so far its not going well.

Here's what I have atm.

```
def find(self):
    target = askstring('Mainwindow','Search string')
    if target:
        where = self.aText.search(target,INSERT,END)
        if where:
            print(where)
            pastit = where + ('+%dc' % len(target))
            self.aText.tag_add(SEL, where, pastit)
            self.aText.mark_set(INSERT, pastit)
            self.aText.see(INSERT)
            self.aText.focus()
```

When I run this it shows this :

AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'aText'

I can open the find window but it won't do what I want and that is of course to find words.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not enough code to actually exhibit the problem.  Presumably, you never actually assigned your text field to ``self.aText``.

Comment: If python is telling you that your app has no attribute named `aText`, then you need to believe it. Since we can't see where you think you define it, we can't say what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this exception, with a solution commented out.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
# root.aText = tk.Text(root)
print(root.aText)
```

This produces

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\mypy\tem.py", line 3, in <module>
    root.aText
  File "C:\Programs\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2095, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'aText'
```

Uncomment the line and get (in the upcoming 3.6.0b4)

```
.!text
```

Now find where you have a typo, if not a missing line.

Note: the constant mistake of beginners is to type way too much code before running and testing.  In my view, you should not have written the `if where:` code until you knew that the `where =` code worked.  And this is assuming that the failure was in the `where =` statement and not in previously run code.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find():
    word=find_input.get()
    text_editor.tag_remove("match","1.0",tk.END)
    matches=0
    if word:
        start_pos="1.0"
        while True:
            start_pos=text_editor.search(word,start_pos,stopindex=tk.END)
            if not start_pos:
                break
            end_pos=f"{start_pos}+{len(word)}c"
            text_editor.tag_add("match",start_pos,end_pos)
            matches+=1
            start_pos=end_pos
            text_editor.tag_config("match",foreground="red",background="yellow")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.